Razor validation for multiple forms
My page is display a table with each row being a item from a list. Each row has a form to allow the user to update a value and submit it (and only it) back to the server. That is all working. However, I wish to add validation so that the number entered must be between 0 and another property of the row item. So I have the following:
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.ItemList) {
        <form method="post">
        <tr>
            <td>..</td>

            <td>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Identifier" />
                <input asp-for="@item.PropertyToUpdate" class="form-control" min="0" max="@item.MaxValue"  id="@item.PropertyToUpdate" />
                
                <span asp-validation-for="@item.PropertyToUpdate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </form>
}
    </tbody>

However, when the user enters the value and leaves the box, the validation message does not display.
Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

You could try this below code to show the error message when user leaves the box:
Index.cshtml:
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Item List";
}

<h2>Item List</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Property to Update</th>
            <th>Max Value</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ItemList)
        {
            <form method="post" class="item-form">
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Identifier</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Identifier" />
                    <input asp-for="@item.PropertyToUpdate"
                           class="form-control"
                           data-max-value="@item.MaxValue"
                           onblur="validateInput(this)" />
                    <span class="text-danger error-message" style="display:none;"></span>
                </td>
                <td>@item.MaxValue</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </form>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function validateInput(input) {
            // Get the max value from the custom attribute
            const maxValue = parseInt($(input).attr("data-max-value"));
            const value = parseInt($(input).val());

            // Find the error message span
            const errorMessageSpan = $(input).siblings(".error-message");

            // Validate the input value
            if (isNaN(value) || value < 0 || value > maxValue) {
                // Show error message if invalid
                errorMessageSpan.text(`Please enter a value between 0 and ${maxValue}.`);
                errorMessageSpan.show();
            } else {
                // Hide error message if valid
                errorMessageSpan.hide();
            }
        }
    </script>
}

Index.cshtml.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using ValidationDemo.Models;

namespace ValidationDemo.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public List<Item> ItemList { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            // Sample data for demonstration
            ItemList = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item { Identifier = 1, MaxValue = 50, PropertyToUpdate = 10 },
                new Item { Identifier = 2, MaxValue = 30, PropertyToUpdate = 5 },
                new Item { Identifier = 3, MaxValue = 80, PropertyToUpdate = 20 },
            };
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost(int identifier, int propertyToUpdate)
        {
            // Process the form submission for the specific item
            var item = ItemList.Find(i => i.Identifier == identifier);
            if (item != null && propertyToUpdate >= 0 && propertyToUpdate <= item.MaxValue)
            {
                item.PropertyToUpdate = propertyToUpdate;
            }

            return Page();
        }


    }
}

Item.cs:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ValidationDemo.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int Identifier { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "MaxValue must be between 0 and 100.")]
        public int MaxValue { get; set; } // Max limit for PropertyToUpdate

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value.")]
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid number between 0 and MaxValue.")]
        public int PropertyToUpdate { get; set; }

    }
}



Apologies for the delay in accepting the answer, life got in the way. Works a treat, thank you
